# Display Chapter Label and Number Below Chapter Title in Memoir Class

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am designing a book with the memoir class. The chapter style should resemble new-high german books with the chapter label and number in a new line after the chapter title, i.e.

A treatise on some renaissance topic

Chapter 1

I could not find any predefined or modified style that makes this possible. Vertical movement of the chapter label is probably not a good idea, because the title may be long and then overlap. How can this be coded?

My structure looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, onecolumn, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\LARGE\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\LARGE\normalfont} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\centering\LARGE\normalfont}
\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\centering\Large\normalfont\noindent}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Caput}}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

   \chapter{A treatise on some renaissance topic}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using an `inverse` chapter style incorporating your fonts:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Caput}}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\makeatletter
\newlength\betweennametitle% to control separation between chapter title and name 
\setlength\betweennametitle{-60pt}

\makechapterstyle{inverse}{
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\normalfont} 
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\normalfont} 
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\centering\LARGE\normalfont}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{10pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{\dimexpr-\betweennametitle+20pt\relax}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
  \def\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \raisebox{\betweennametitle}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \vphantom{{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}%
    }\afterchapternum\vskip\onelineskip\vskip-\topskip%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \raisebox{\betweennametitle}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \makebox[\textwidth]{{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}\chapternamenum{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{inverse}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test numbered chapter}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

Please, don't load `fontenc` nor `inputenc` with fontspec`.